# How can I make "onload" waiting for "fetch" complete?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fetch

Long story short, I'll show the code.

**some.html**

```
<html><script src="some.js"></script></html>
```

**some.js**

```
window.onload = () => console.log( "onload" );
(async (url, cb) => cb( await ( await fetch(url) ).json() ))
( "some.json", () => console.log( "in async" ) );
```

and some.html outputs:

```
onload
in async
```

I've done some works e.g. image loading in real fetch, so `fetch().then()` doesn't work for me.

Now my question is as title says, how can I let "onload" waiting for "fetch" complete?

Comment: Why does not `fetch().then()` work for 'you'?

Comment: `window.onload = () => console.log( "onload" );` . that sets the onload handler function ... the rest is completely separate code

Comment: @MarkusZeller because I need to do some job after e.g. images loading complete, can `then` catch this?

Comment: how about something like https://pastebin.com/8jT4yPNL

Comment: @JaromandaX Cool thing! Would you please just write same text as an answer ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I think you are trying to achieve is the fetch starts before window.onload, but onload needs to wait for the fetch before doing anything else ...

```
const promiseOfSomeData = fetch("some.json").then(r=>r.json()).then(data => {
    console.log('in async');
    return data;
});
window.onload = async () => {
    let someData = await promiseOfSomeJsonData;
    console.log("onload");
};
```

Comment: Well, I made a mistake, in this way `onload` triggers before all images loaded ... in `fetch` function I write some DOM operations, how can I trigger a function when page really completely loaded?

Comment: erm, I can only go by the code you posted, with the code you posted, this is correct, with your actual code, only you know - it seems `window.onload` is *not the event you are looking for™* - though, window.onload triggers when the page is completely loaded (anything you "load" using fetch is NOT waited for by onload - but then, that's the whole point of this answer, isn't it)

Comment: Well I've tried several times today, none works. So is there any way to let "onload" waiting for "fetch"? Or I must fall back to `httprequest`?

Comment: I can tell you right now that `console.log("onload");` won't happen until AFTER `promiseOfSomeData` is "complete" ... I don't know why you keep going on about "images" since nothing in your code suggests anything to do with images

Comment: If we wait for onload outside of window (eg. in iframe) - that method doesn't work

Comment: @dy_ I forgot, iframes don't have `window` - thank god you're here to correct my code