# Can I add custom headers while trying to preload XHR data?

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, fetch, preload

I am firing an XHR from JS code. This render-blocking XHR is fired on every page load, so I want to fetch it early in page's lifecycle, in parallel with JS and CSS resources. Inside my `index.html`, I'll add the following code:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="preload" as="fetch" href="/xhr-to-be-fetched-early">
</head>
```

The XHR request needs some custom headers such as `authorization` & `Accept`. Is there any way to add these headers to `link` tag, either inside HTML itself or via JS? Or is it impossible to cache such requests?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot truly add headers to a `<link>` tag, but you can stop the page from loading anything until the resource is fetched.

See something like this:

```js
const promiseOfSomeData = fetch("URL.com", { 
    // This is where you set the headers
    headers: {
        'X-My-Cool-Header': 'here'
    }
}).then(data => {
    return data;
});
window.onload = async () => {
    let someData = await promiseOfSomeJsonData;
    console.log(someData)
};
```

[How can I make "onload" waiting for "fetch" complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57935675/how-can-i-make-onload-waiting-for-fetch-complete)

Comment: Thanks! This is an interesting solution. For my use case, the XHR request needs to be fired from a different JS file. That can be done by storing promise in a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

you can't add custom headers in the `link` request; when you use `as` to specify the type of content, browsers will automatically apply the correct headers based on the content type, but you don't have access to this lifecycle.

you could use a `<script async></script>` instead, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-async, and perform the `fetch` with extra headers. It will be executed in parallel with other resources of the page.

Comment: Manually firing an XHR doesn't seem to help with preloading it. I mean, if I fire the same XHR from application code, it is taking the same amount of time. It isn't instantaneous as is expected from cached responses. I checked the headers for both requests are exactly the same. Maybe it's because of Cache-control: no-cache header. From all this, I guess preload is more suited for my use case, and I don't have any option but to match the headers set by preload HTML tag.

Answer (score 1):

A unique situation, although, I have an idea popping in my mind that says how about you replace your preload link with a small JS snippet that requests the data using XHR, or `fetch`, or whatever method you prefer. Replace this:

```
<link rel="preload" as="fetch" href="/xhr-to-be-fetched-early">
```

with this:

```
<script async>
    fetch('target-url', {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            //add headers here
        }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => console.log("Preloaded", response))
</script>
```

Hope it helps, see more about `fetch` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

`async` attribute in the script tag isn't necessary but it'll help reduce the load times if the data is kinda large.